# Perl Syntax Error : Sample Program to read a file

Tags: perl, syntax-error

I am getting the an error while reading a file and below is the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
$file = "SampleLogFile.txt";    #--- line 2 
open(MYINPUTFILE,$file);        #--- line 3  
while(<**MYINPUTFILE**>) { 

# Good practice to store $_ value because
# subsequent operations may change it.
my($line) = $_;

# Good practice to always strip the trailing
# newline from the line.
chomp($line);

# Convert the line to upper case.
print "$line" if $line = ~ /sent/;

}
close (MYINPUTFILE);
```

**Output :**

PerlTesting_New.ksh[2]: =:  not found
PerlTesting_New.ksh[3]: syntax error at line 3 : `(' unexpected

Any idea what the issue is ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
#!/bin/bash
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

Otherwise Perl will not be interpreting your script. Change path accordingly as per your system

Comment: An interpreter line of '!#/usr/bin/env perl' is useful to find Perl wherever it can be found in your PATH.

Comment: I am a newbie and Still the same error though I changed as per

Comment: How are you invoking the script?

Comment: @whokares: It is not a ksh script, it is a perl one. Invoke it with `perl scriptname.ksh`. Changing the name to `scriptname.perl` (or `.pl` or `.prl`) would also be desirable.

Comment: @choroba Ohhhh man... U fired itther .. Thanks a lot .. It was so confusng ..Its working now  Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Okay, whoever is teaching you to write Perl like this needs to move out of the nineties.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;   # ALWAYS
use warnings; # Also always.  

# When you learn more you can selectively turn off bits of strict and warnings
# functionality  on an as needed basis.


use IO::File; # A nice OO module for working with files.

my $file_name = "SampleLogFile.txt"; # note that we have to declare $file now.

my $input_fh = IO::File->new( $file_name, '<' );  # Open the file read-only using IO::File.

# You can avoid assignment through $_ by assigning to a variable, even when you use <$fh>   

while( my $line = $input_fh->getline() ) { 

    # chomp($line); # Chomping is usually a good idea.  
                    # In this case it does nothing but screw up 
                    # your output, so I commented it out.

    # This does nothing of the sort:
    # Convert the line to upper case.
    print "$line" if $line = ~ /sent/;

}
```

You can also do this with a one liner:

```
perl -pe '$_ = "" unless /sent/;'  SampleLogFile.txt
```

See [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#%2a-p%2a) for more info on one-liners.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, your first line : #!/bin/bash

/bin/bash : This is the Bash shell.

You may need to change to

## !/usr/bin/perl

Comment: the same erro as I posted above